# Trying to upgrade npm in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

Hello I'm trying to upgrade `npm` in Windows 10 and I've searched a lot about the  **Scripts cannot be executed on this system** problem. I ran the script

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

before I ran
`npm-windows-upgrade`

but it gives me:

> npm-windows-upgrade v5.0.0
>
> Scripts cannot be executed on this system.
> To fix, run the command below as Administrator in PowerShell and try again:
> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force

and I ran PowerShell as administrator too. Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the execution policy will only work if it's not enforced with a local or group policy. Check your local or group policy to see if there are any restrictions set, if there are no restrictions

Then, to install and use this upgrader tool, run (also from an elevated PowerShell or cmd.exe):

```
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Check out this article on upgrading npm on Windows:

[npm-windows-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade)